# Getting an odd error, SQL Server query using `WITH` clause

Tags: sql-server

The following query:

```
WITH 
    CteProductLookup(ProductId, oid) 
    AS 
    (
        SELECT p.ProductID, p.oid
        FROM [dbo].[ME_CatalogProducts] p 
    )

SELECT 
    rel.Name as RelationshipName,
    pl.ProductId as FromProductId,
    pl2.ProductId as ToProductId
FROM 
    (
    [dbo].[ME_CatalogRelationships] rel 
    INNER JOIN CteProductLookup pl 
    ON pl.oid = rel.from_oid
    ) 
    INNER JOIN CteProductLookup pl2 
    ON pl2.oid = rel.to_oid
WHERE
    rel.Name = 'BundleItem' AND
    pl.ProductId = 'MX12345';
```

Is generating this error:

> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'with'. If this statement is a common
>   table expression, an xmlnamespaces
>   clause or a change tracking context
>   clause, the previous statement must be
>   terminated with a semicolon.

On **execution** only. There are no errors/warnings in the sql statement in the managment studio.

Any ideas?

Comment: why even use a CTE here? couldn't you just join to the actual table `[dbo].[ME_CatalogProducts]` instead of the cte `CteProductLookup`, which doesn't really do anything?

Comment: For Extension later, but you're right I don't need it in this example.

Comment: It appears you can get this message by having more than one `with` statement. you only need one for the first, then use a comma and just give the name for the next one with columns in brackets ad infinitum. You don't need a comma after last one, and then you can just select it

Answer (score 148, accepted):

always use with statement like `;WITH` then you'll never get this error.  The WITH command required a `;` between it and any previous command, by always using `;WITH` you'll never have to remember to do this.

see [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx), from the section *Guidelines for Creating and Using Common Table Expressions:*

> When a CTE is used in a statement that
>   is part of a batch, the statement
>   before it must be followed by a
>   semicolon.

Comment: SQL Server is moving towards requiring statements to be terminated by semicolons. SQL2012 requires them in many more places than just CTEs and Merge statements. This fix seems to be a hack for a bug in their  implementation.

Comment: Unless they are going to "fix" all their TSQL code, yes it is a "hack".  Otherwise, this will make it work, especially if you are just maintaining some legacy code. It is a good thing to be aware of, so you can plan for your upgrade.  There are some automated tools that will add semicolons for you.

Answer (score 23):

```
;WITH 
    CteProductLookup(ProductId, oid) 
    AS 
...
```

Answer (score 6):

It should be legal to put a semicolon directly before the WITH keyword.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases this also occurs if you have table hints and you have spaces between WITH clause and your hint, so best to type it like:

```
SELECT Column1 FROM Table1 t1 WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 WITH(NOLOCK) ON t1.Column1 = t2.Column1
```

And not:

```
SELECT Column1 FROM Table1 t1 WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON t1.Column1 = t2.Column1
```