# How do you create contiguous numbers in a field using a SQL Server trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that allocates sequential booking numbers to session bookings. These numbers are printed on tickets, a bit like seat numbers on a movie ticket.

1. When a SessionBooking record is created, I want the trigger to allocate the BookingNumber.
2. If a SessionBooking is logically deleted (IsDeleted = 1) the BookingNumber should be set to NULL
3. When a SessionBooking is logically deleted, the BookingNumber should be reallocated the next time a SessionBooking is created.
4. The Session also maintains a BookingCount of SessionBookings that are not logically deleted
5. Once a BookingNumber has been allocated, it shouldn't be changed (unless it is deleted)

The relevant part of the database schema is:

```
----- -----------------
Table Session 
----- -----------------
PK    SessionID
int   BookingCount      (count of SessionBookings)

----- -----------------
Table SessionBooking
----- -----------------
PK    SessionBookingID
FK    SessionID
int   BookingNumber     (allows nulls)
bool  IsDeleted         (1 = deleted)
```

This is what I have so far. It seems far too complicated to me and for some reason some times when I create a SessionBooking the BookingNumber remains NULL.

For some crazy reason I can't post this as text, I have to use a screen capture...

[image]

Comment: For some reason I can't post the SQL of the trigger in the question - I just get errors.

Comment: Does you trigger really have to fire for `DELETE`s? It's odd to have a setup where a table experiences both logical deletes (`IsDeleted=`) and physical deletes.

Comment: You're right, physical deletes don't really happen, except when you modify a record and it appears in the INSERTED and DELETED tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find the next unused booking number.

```
;with live as (select * from sessionBooking where isdeleted=0)
select isnull(min(t1.bookingNumber)+1,1)
from live t1
    left join live t2 on t1.bookingNumber+1=t2.bookingNumber
where t2.bookingnumber is null
```

Comment: I tried something like this (but with an inner join) but it failed when creating the first record because there were no existing records.

Comment: This didn't do it, but +1 because I didn't know about the WITH statement and I think that's sending me in the right direction.

Comment: @DerekTomes I've adjusted it to work for the no records situation.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up with a slightly different answer but this got me there in the end. What's with the `;with` statement? Does that get around StackOverflow blocking valid answers or is it some other cryptic thing?

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746916/getting-an-odd-error-sql-server-query-using-with-clause