# Display last streak

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
ID  HomeTeam     AwayTeam     FTHG  FTAG    WDL
1   Anderlecht   Lokeren      2     3       W
2   Lokeren      Bergen       2     1       W
3   Kortrijk     Lokeren      3     3       D
4   Oud-Heverlee Lokeren      2     1       L
5   Lokeren      Oostende     1     0       W
6   Charleroi    Lokeren      2     1       L
7   Lokeren      Gent         2     2       D
8   Club Brugge  Lokeren      1     0       L
9   Lokeren      Mechelen     4     0       W
10  Lokeren      Club Brugge  0     3       L
```

I like to count last streak of Lokeren

for example the last game Lokeren lost the result should look like this

```
team        wdl       count
Lokeren      L          1
```

Comment: Providing requirements without showing any effort was once considered [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It is still [being debated now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215596/are-code-questions-without-an-attempt-now-on-topic), and many people consider it to be rude.

Comment: You must re edit your database table

Comment: sorry for this but I am new to sql server and to stackoverflow I stack to this 3 days searching for solution

Comment: @AleksandarNikoloski what version of sql server? sql server 2012 supports lag/lead analytic functions whereas 2008 does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes you're using sql server 2012 (support for analytic functions is lower in 2008).

```
with sub as
 (select x.*,
         row_number() over(partition by wdl order by id) - row_number() over(order by id) as grp
    from (select id, hometeam as team, wdl
            from tbl
           where hometeam = 'Lokeren'
          union all
          select id,
                 awayteam,
                 case when wdl = 'W' then 'L' else 'W' end
            from tbl
           where awayteam = 'Lokeren') x)
select team, wdl, count(*) as count
  from sub
 where grp = (select grp from sub where id = (select max(id) from sub))
 group by team, wdl
```

You can see a fiddle demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bc4d7/4/0

I added an 11th game where they also lose, for test purposes.

Comment: i'am using sql server 2012 but when i put this in my code file gives me a error Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 446
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon. I tried to solve that by no luck!!!

Comment: @AleksandarNikoloski as you can see from the fiddle there are no syntax errors. If you are running it in a batch w/ other queries, you can try putting a semicolon before the word WITH (ie.    ";with" ), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746916/getting-an-odd-error-sql-server-query-using-with-clause

Comment: when I put the code in my query and change lokeren with @team for loop for some team gives me 2 results. when I put in a #table gives me Null. How do I solve this?