# Incorrect syntax near 'C:'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'

Tags: c#, asp.net

Incorrect syntax near 'C:'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

```
SqlConnection objcon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();

protected void btnBackup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string _DatabaseName = ddlDatabases.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
        string _BackupName = _DatabaseName + "_" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + ".bak";
        objcon.Open();
        string sqlQuery = "BACKUP DATABASE " + _DatabaseName + " TO DISK = 'C:\\SQLServerBackups\\" + _BackupName + "' WITH FORMAT, MEDIANAME = 'Z_SQLServerBackups', NAME = '" + _BackupName + "';";
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, objcon);
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        int iRows = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        objcon.Close();
        lblMessage.Text = "The " + _DatabaseName + " database Backup with the name " + _BackupName + " successfully...";
        ReadBackupFiles();
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlException)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = sqlException.Message.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = exception.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting an odd error, SQL Server query using \`WITH\` clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746916/getting-an-odd-error-sql-server-query-using-with-clause)

Comment: can anyone please help

Comment: Also, don't just post code and an error message. Give some context, tell us what you tried.

Comment: Try finding out what sqlQuery contains when it errors out.

Comment: @Sachu That won't change anything.

Comment: i'm doing my college project in visual studio 2012 i've created a database and i want to implement backup and recovery in my project for the database

Comment: @RobertMcKee at first sight i thought its bcos of ' coming in between the query

Comment: i'm doing my project using asp.net and c#

Comment: @MohammedZubair also always try to avoid this type of sql command..always try to create sql command with parameter binded..this type of sql string can cause sql injection

Comment: i have given a dropdown list where i've written the query select * from sys.databases after selecting one of the datbase when i'm clicking the backup command button where i've the code as mentioned above i'm getting the error

Comment: Which "C:" drive are you talking about? Usually the backup only works to the drives that are local to the database server, so not to *your* local drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SqlConnection objcon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");
    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
    protected void btnBackup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string _DatabaseName = ddlDatabases.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
            string cleandb=Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_DatabaseName);
            string _BackupName = cleandb + "_" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + ".bak";
            objcon.Open();
            string sqlQuery = "BACKUP DATABASE [" + _DatabaseName + "] TO DISK='C:\\SQLServerBackups\\" + _BackupName + "'";
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, objcon);
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            int iRows = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            objcon.Close();
            lblMessage.Text = "The " + _DatabaseName + " database Backup with the name " + _BackupName + " successfully...";
            ReadBackupFiles();
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlException)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = sqlException.Message.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = exception.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I've removed the extra parameters on the backup command, surrounded the database name with brackets, and removed the spaces around the equals sign in `DISK =`

Comment: i'm getting this error bro...Cannot open backup device 'C:\SQLServerBackups\C:\USERS\MOHAMMED ZUBAIR\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2012\PROJECTS\WEBAPPLICATION11\WEBAPPLICATION11\APP_DATA\DATABASE1.MDF_18_5_2015.bak'. Operating system error 123(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.). BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: You've got an incorrect path there.  It looks like your databasename is coming across as a path.

Comment: Where is the backup - is it `C:\SQLServerBackups` or `C:\USERS\MOHAMMED ZUBAIR\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2012\PROJECTS\WEBAPPLICATION11\WEBAPPLICATION11\APP_DATA`?  You have both in your path.

Comment: Updated code to pull just the base filename from _Database.

Comment: C:\SQLServerBackups is the destination where the backup has tobe done