# SQL update rows to point to single key, then remove duplicates

Tags: sql, duplicates

I'm fixing an old database structure.  Old table was storing an image (I've simplified this a lot):

**Game**

```
GameId, int
Name, varchar(50)
Picture, image
```

The table allowed rows with the same "Name" and that meant the same "Picture" existed...so we were wasting space by storing a duplicate image.  We decided to move Picture/image into its own table.

**Game**

```
GameId, int
Name, varchar(50)
PictureId, int
```

**Picture**

```
PictureId, int
Picture, image
```

I have the SQL commands to do everything about moving the image column to the new table (and the image data itself), but I still have Game rows with the same "Name" pointing to their own Picture row (via Game.PictureId).  I want all Game columns with the same "Name" pointing to a single Picture record.

What is the SQL command(s) to point all Game rows with the same "Name" to a single Picture row, then delete the duplicate Picture rows since no Game records use them any more?

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far? and can we see sample data and desired results please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddle Link here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a2085/1

```
;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT name, max(pictureid) as pid
    FROM game
   GROUP BY name
)
UPDATE game 
   SET pictureid = b.pid
  FROM game a
       INNER JOIN
       cte b ON a.name = b.name;

delete from picture where pictureid not in (
select pictureid from game);
```

Comment: One additional note, using SQL 2016 (and other prev versions), I was getting an "incorrect syntax near" on the WITH statement.  The solution was to start with statement with a semicolon, ";WITH...".  This solution was found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746916/getting-an-odd-error-sql-server-query-using-with-clause)

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't really matter to which of the duplicate images the `Game` rows will point, you can use something like

```
UPDATE Game g 
SET PictureId = 
  (SELECT MIN(g2.PictureId) from Game g2 where g2.Name = g.Name)
```

After this you can proceed to remove `Picture` rows without any games pointing them.

Comment: Dangerous; no workie.  that sets every Game.PictureId to to lowest of all PictureIds that exist.  You can't do an UPDATE Game [g].