# SQL "WITH" doesn't work in Spotfire

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, spotfire

I try to run a query in Spotfire (7.8) from a MS SQL server.

Everything works well with simple queries, however I can't get Common table expressions get working.

This is a very simple example which run without issues from MS SQL Server Management studio:

```
with test as ( select * from myTable)
select * from test
```

In Spotfire I get following error:

> An error occurred when executing a query in the external data source.
>
> External error:
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a
>   common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking
>   context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a
>   semicolon.
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I've tried adding `;` as suggested also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746916/getting-an-odd-error-sql-server-query-using-with-clause), but it didn't help:

> An error occurred when executing a query in the external data source.
>
> External error:
>   Incorrect syntax near ';'.
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I've played a bit adding `;`s to various location (after end of select statements, closing brackets...), but couldn't get it working.

My real query is very long, so putting everything together and getting rid of CTEs is not really an option.

Just for clarification, I've tried all below positions and also combinations without success:

```
;with test as ( select * from myTable)
select * from test 

with test as ( select * from myTable;)
select * from test 

with test as ( select * from myTable);
select * from test
```

Comment: I would suggest getting your sql out of the application code. Put this in a stored procedure and you don't have to fight applications and the sometimes quite strange way they deal with queries.

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for the suggestion! How can I do that in Spotfire?

Comment: I have no idea how you call a procedure in spotfire (never heard of it before), but if it can execute a query it can execute a procedure. I would look at google, I suspect there are plenty of examples.

Comment: @MátéJuhász you wouldn't do that in Spotfire; that's the point Sean is trying to make. create a stored procedure in MSSQL and then access the proc in Spotfire. if this is confusing for you then please provide more detail about your environment and through what mechanism you're trying to import this data (e.g., information link vs db connection).

Comment: Sounds like Spotfire is running some kind of other query in the same batch, causing the CTE to fail, as it's using deprecated functionality (not terminating it's statements with a semi colon(`;`). @SeanLange definately has the right idea here. However, an alternate solution might be (can't believe I'm suggesting this...) is to use `;` as a "begininator", rather than a terminator. I.E. `;WITH CTE AS...`. Personally, i really dislike that and using a Stored procedure would be a far better idea. (I really dislike statements which start with a semicolon...).

Comment: Also dont know what spotfire is. But basic tips for question is show your current code. Right now you only show a working sql code and that doesnt give us anything to work. You should show the spotfire code so if someone know about can see what is wrong.

Comment: Guys thanks for the suggestion. [Spotfire](https://spotfire.tibco.com/) is  data analysis and visualization tool. I don't have more code then I've posted already, everything is done in a wizard where I select connection properties and enter SQL statements. Spotfire supports scripting, but I'm afraid it will try to pass my SQL through the same process as currently. Also, scripting would require different access level than I currently have.

Comment: Sounds like you put the `;` in all the places except the correct one. Before `;with`. It even says so in your error message `If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the *previous statement* must be terminated with a semicolon.` You should still go with the procedure method, it's way easier to maintain.

Comment: @JacobH I've tried that too, please see my update. I can not use procedures the same way as data connections in Spotfire.

Comment: Spotfire can mangle your query in all sorts of creative ways that can break things. You can break out a profiler and see what statement it actually sends to the server to get some idea of how it fails and how to work around that, or you can (alas) simply give up and not use a CTE. CTEs are only required if you want recursion; if that's not needed, any query using a CTE can always be rewritten to use subqueries instead (`SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ...) AS test`).

Comment: Would like to point out, @JacobH , the error says `the **previous statement** must be terminated` not `the current statement must begin with`. The semicolon(`;`) doesn't go at the start of the `WITH` statement, it should go at the end of the previous statement, as the error states. ;)

Comment: @Larnu OP also implied they have multiple statements going and hasn't included the code so this whole conversation is kind of pointless except that we know OP isn't using `;` properly even though they think they are.

Comment: @Larnu: there is no previous statement.

Comment: Are you sure your server version is > 2000 and you use appropriate driver? I also suggest you to use Profiler to see exactly what is sent to server

Comment: @MátéJuhász there has to be if the error is the one above. That's what the error means. For example `SELECT 1 AS a WITH CTE AS(SELECT 1 AS a) SELECT a FROM CTE` will not work. On the other hand `SELECT 1 AS a; WITH CTE AS(SELECT 1 AS a) SELECT a FROM CTE;` does.

Comment: @Jeroen "You can break out a profiler and see what statement it actually sends to the server" - how?  I know I could get rid of CTEs, but as I've already mentioned I'd prefer nor to.  My real query is currently 300+ line long, putting everything together would make it very difficult to manage.

Comment: How? By [downloading the latest version of SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms), installing it and [reading the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler). (If you already have some version of Management Studio installed, the first step is of course optional. Note that SSMS is typically also installed on the server itself.)

Comment: @MátéJuhász Assuming your have SSMS installed: `Start Menu -> All programs -> Microsoft SQL Server [Your Version Here] -> Performance Tools -> SQL Server [Your Version Here] Profiler`

Comment: @Jeroen: I don't understand how that can help, the same query works well in SSMS, I've the issue only in Spotfire

Comment: @Larnu: I don't understand how that can help, the same query works well in SSMS, I've the issue only in Spotfire

Comment: My point is that Spotfire is transforming your query into something else, and that "something else" contains a syntax error. You won't know what it does (and if you can work around it) until you trace it. You are assuming Spotfire is executing your query as-is. My contention is that it's not. Therefore, your SSMS tests mean little.

Comment: Completely agree with @JeroenMostert here. Saying "the query works in SSMS" isn't telling us anything, as clearly Spotfire isn't running that query you have; from the error message it's clearly running another quiery in the same batch and not terminating the query using a `;` (as it should be).

Comment: Guys I'm lost:( I've an issue in spotfire and toy give me slightly related suggestions which I don't understands ad I'm not an expert with databases (otherwise I probably wouldn't need to ask). Please give specific suggestions.

Comment: Voting that this be closed due to not having enough information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: chiming in again to suggest that you update your question with more details about how you are creating this connection. if you are using the information designer, then double check that your connection object is using the Microsoft driver (instead of the DataDirect one). if that still doesn't work, the answer below from Chelsea is the best way. if you don't know what a stored procedure is, you need to talk to your DBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR If you have all the right permissions, and have used Spotfire more than once or twice, make a stored procedure (see below for details).  If you haven't, sorry, you're going to have to put the CTEs all together into one really long query.

---

So I have found that Spotfire will only actually run "one query" in a standard Information Link or Direct Connection.

Sadly, this means that it doesn't get along very well with temp tables or CTEs.

**If leaving everything together really isn't an option, you will have to turn it into a stored procedure**, as Sean mentioned in the comments.

The only downside to this, is it requires more access than a lot of Spotfire users have.

First things first, you will need to create your stored procedure in your database, or contact someone who can create the stored procedure for you.

Second, you will need to use the Information Designer (which, again, requires the correct permissions).  If you have access, Information Designer is located under Tools.  When you open it up, you will have "Create Information Link" at the top, and below that you will see things like "Create Elements" which includes "Procedure".

[image: InformationDesigner]

This is where you select the stored procedure from your data sources.

You then need to make an Information Link ("Create Information Link"), and select the Procedure you just built, which will now be in the "Elements" tab.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I can't create stored procedure, so I'll keep using other tools:(