# SQL Server: Count distinct, then union multiple fields

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server database table has these columns:

- `[company]`: name of company sending email
- `[email1]`: is primary email recipient
- `[email2]`: secondary email recipient (nullable)

The database has hundreds of unique companies.

I'd like to count how many unique email-ids over `[email1]` and `[email2]` combined each `[company]` has sent emails to.

Edit: added a sample table below, note an email id that appears in `[email1]` in one communication may appear in `[email2]` in another and vice-versa:

```
company         email1              email2
---------------------------------------------------
company1        person1@abc.com     person2@abc.com
company1        person2@abc.com     person3@abc.com
company2        person1@xyz.com     person2@xyz.com
company2        person1@123.com     person2@123.com
```

So the result should look like this:

```
company         numUniqueEmails
---------------------------------
company1        3
company2        4
```

Comment: Could you please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sure, added into OP

Comment: thanks... ideally you need to show us what you have tried... your question, just displays the table structure... please note that Stackoverflow is not code writing service...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query to count unique email id for each company:

```
select company, count(*) numUniqueEmails
from (
  select distinct company, email1 from tablename
  union
  select distinct company, email2 from tablename
) tbl
group by company
```

Same result can be achieved using a CTE:

```
with cte
as (
  select distinct company, email1  from tablename
  union
  select distinct company, email2 from tablename
)
select company, count(*) numUniqueEmails 
from cte
group by company
```

Comment: Remember there are '00s of companies?

Comment: @shanlodh - You can use any of the above-updated queries. Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted your answer. I did not realise that `select distinct` actually spans all following columns

Comment: a semi-colon is required before 'with' in the case of the cte, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746916/getting-an-odd-error-sql-server-query-using-with-clause)

Comment: @shanlodh - you need semi-colon with "With" Statement when you have any previous statement, if "with" is your first statement then no need of semi-colon.