# Error with keyword 'WITH' OPENJSON in SQL

Tags: json, sql-server

I am getting a weird error message in a simple OPENJSON query

```
DECLARE @json VARCHAR(MAX) = N'[{"name":"jsmith","fullAccess":0,"activatedOn":"2019-05-20T00:00:00"}]'
DECLARE @isAdmin int 
SET @isAdmin = (SELECT fullAccess FROM OPENJSON (@json) WITH (fullAccess int N'$.fullAccess'))
PRINT @isAdmin
```

The error I am getting is:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'WITH'.
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 8 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an
>   xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous
>   statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746916/getting-an-odd-error-sql-server-query-using-with-clause) solution without success. My SQL version is 13.0.5026

Comment: I run, it returns 0. I am using 14.0.

Comment: What is your COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL?

Comment: @HoneyBadger COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL is 120.

Comment: As clearly [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), `OPENJSON` requires compat level 130 or higher. 120 is SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert), changing the Compatibility Level solved the issue.

```
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130
```